# passing one function to different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, function

I have to create an application where I'll have to make multiple threads. SoI thought to try making one function and passing it to different threads. Initially I've created two threads and have declared one function to be passed to both of them. All I am trying to do is to pass different integers to those threads and display it in the thread function,here is my code:

```
DWORD WINAPI Name(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    int *Ptr=(int*)lpParam;

    for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
        cout<<"Thread"<<endl;
        cout<<*Ptr<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int a=10,b=15,c=25;
    HANDLE thread1,thread2;
    DWORD threadID,threadID2;
    thread2= CreateThread(NULL,0,Name,LPVOID(a),0,&threadID2);
    thread1= CreateThread(NULL,0,Name,LPVOID(b),0,&threadID);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Main Thread"<<endl;
    }

    if(thread1==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Couldn't Create Thread:("<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    if(thread2==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Couldn't Create Thread:("<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but this code is not running properly,i.e compliles fine,starts fine but afterwards gives a debugging error.
Could someone let let me know of my mistake and how I could correct it coz being able to utilize one function for multiple threads will be really helpful for me.

Comment: Try `int Ptr = (int)lpParam;` instead.

Comment: **You're not waiting in the main thread.** See the documentation of  `WaitForSingleObject()` and `WaitForMultipleObjects()` on msdn.

Comment: @ Kerrek SB,hey that works!!!,although uptil now I was of the opinion that it's not possible,can you please tell me how this worked?

Comment: @AaymanKhalid: `void *` is an integral type. You can store integers in it.

Comment: @KerrekSB: a more robust way would be to pass `LPVOID(&a)` to the thread, and keep using `int *Ptr=(int*)lpParam;`: `int` is not guaranteed to be the same size as `void*`, eg. on a 64 bit system.

Comment: @ Kerrek SB,so what if I want to pass a string to it,will it still work?

Comment: @AaymanKhalid: see my previous comment. In short: passing by reference (actually by pointer) rather than by value will allow you to use any type. Also, as a general advice, you should use C++ casts (`static_cast` et al.) instead of unchecked legacy C casts, they catch some programmer errors earlier (like your original mixing of integral types and pointers).

Comment: @syam,Thank you:) and could you tell me the difference between the two casting techniques???advantages and disadvantages...

Comment: @AaymanKhalid: the only advantage of legacy C cast is that it is easier to *write*. It's harder to *read* later, and doesn't check the validity of the cast, allowing you to make more errors. C++ casts are more legible, and unless you use `reinterpret_cast` (which you should avoid if possible) they also do basic compile-time checks on the cast-from/cast-to types to ensure compatibility. You can still make errors, but less often.

Answer (score 3):

Wait for your child threads to return. Do this:

```
int main()
{
    int a=10,b=15,c=25;
    HANDLE thread[2];
    DWORD threadID,threadID2;
    thread[1]= CreateThread(NULL,0,Name,LPVOID(a),0,&threadID2);
    thread[0]= CreateThread(NULL,0,Name,LPVOID(b),0,&threadID);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Main Thread"<<endl;
    }

    if(thread[0]==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Couldn't Create Thread:("<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    if(thread[1]==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Couldn't Create Thread:("<<endl;
        CloseHandle(thread[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    WaitForMultipleObjects(2, thread, TRUE, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(thread[0]);
    CloseHandle(thread[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The handle of a thread is signaled when the thread is terminated (refer [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the address of a local variable in the function into your thread. By the time the thread gets around to running your function has probably exited main already. So the thread will try to access a variable that no longer exists on the stack so will be reading some random value which when you try to dereference it as a pointer will likely crash.

You main needs to wait. For a simple test just put in a Sleep(10000) or something before it exits. Obviously that's no use for a real program.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the comments: There are two ways you can pass data. Either directly inside the void pointer, because "void pointer" is an integral type and thus can represent integers (but it doesn't necessarily have the same width as `int`), or indirectly by passing an actual address of the thing you care about.

**Method 1 (pass the value):**

```
DWORD WINAPI Name(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    intptr_t n = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(lpParam);
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    intptr_t a = 10;

    thread1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Name, reinterpret_cast<void *>(a), 0, &threadID);
    // ...                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

For this method, we use the integral type `intptr_t`, which has the same width as `void *`. We use reinterpret-casts to store and retrieve arbitrary integral values.

**Method 2 (pass a pointer):**

```
DWORD WINAPI Name(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    T * p = static_cast<T *>(lpParam);

    // ...  use *p ...
}

int main()
{
    T thing_I_care_about;

    thread1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Name, &thing_I_care_about, 0, &threadID);
    // ...                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

This is the more general method, but requires that `thing_I_care_about` remain alive, and it becomes a brittle shared state, so lifetime management and synchronisation become issues. Note that any object pointer is implicitly convertible to `void *`, so there's no need for the cast at the call site.

Finally, as others have commented, don't forget to join or detach your threads.